# Angular adding code snippet show error

Tags: angular

I trying to add this code in my angular project in app.component.ts file but it show me an error

```
var options = {
  facebook: "facebook_id", // Facebook page ID
  whatsapp: "+XXXXXXXXX", // WhatsApp number
  call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
  button_color: "#008000", // Color of button
  position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
  order: "facebook,whatsapp", // Order of buttons
};
var proto = document.location.protocol,
  host = "whatshelp.io",
  url = proto + "//static." + host;
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
s.onload = function() {
  WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options);
};
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
```

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: What is `WhWidgetSendButton`? Sounds like you forgot to import that dependency?

Comment: 4.1.3 @KrishnaRathore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare  `WhWidgetSendButton` in `app.component.ts`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adding-code-snippet-show-error?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts)**

```
declare var WhWidgetSendButton;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```